# Transfer data to rMBP from external hard drive?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, migration

I got the new rMBP and tried importing my stuff to it via an external HD. Seems like it didn't work. And Migration Assistant didn't either. Has anyone done this successfully?

Comment: What exactly means "didn't work"?

Comment: Indeed.  Please clarify.  Surey copies directly from drive to drive worked :|.